# Get 401 error after upload picture on Windows server with PHP

Tags: php, file, file-upload, upload, iis-7

I upload picutre on server (Win 2008 R2) but i can't open in browser. When I access to server with teamviewer i find that picutre and open normaly.
I have all promision on flders and files and php_fileinfo.dll extension enabled. My project is in YII2.

Comment: Change permission of upload directory

Comment: Upload directory have full controll promision for everone.